# Connecting Power or removing it causes Ubuntu 12.10 to Hang and Crash

Tags: 12.10, power-management, battery

When I boot my machine on battery and later connect the power supply Ubuntu just hangs and crashes and vice verse.

I run Jupiter 0.1.9 it never gave me any issue but yesterday I updated ubuntu there was no update for Jupiter (may have missed it) but since then I have this issue.

Can someone please help?

I can provide all the logs or any outputs needed from me.

Comment: What is your PC/laptop?

Comment: Laptop HP DV6 2140ee

Comment: This sounds like a bug in Jupiter. If you remove it does the problem still happen? If that's the case it's offtopic for the thi forum. The Jupiter site says that it's been retired and is no longer in active development: http://sourceforge.net/projects/jupiter/

Comment: oh ok i shall try uninstalling it and see if there are any issues and update here.

Answer (score 2):

First of all thank you to Melon and bcbc for replying to my question.

As bcbc pointed out Jupiter application the development has stopped but I m not sure if it was updated few days ago cause until then everything seemed fine.

I have uninstalled Jupiter and really happy to let you all know that my laptop is working like a charm.

Thank you all once again for your help. Have a lovely holiday ahead. Cheers.

This issue is closed.